# pandas: duplicates with condition

Tags: python, pandas

Take the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a',0,3],
                            ['b',3,3],
                            ['c',5,6],
                           ['a',3,4]
                           ,['b',0,2]]), columns=['id','y','z'])

df
Out[3]: 
  id  y  z
0  a  0  3
1  b  3  3
2  c  5  6
3  a  3  4
4  b  0  2
```

I want to remove all duplicates which have a value of 0 on the y column. See my attempt below:

```
df.loc[(~df.duplicated('id')) | ((df.duplicated('id'))&(df['y'].astype(int)>0)),:]
Out[4]: 
  id  y  z
0  a  0  3
1  b  3  3
2  c  5  6
3  a  3  4
```

as you can see it only removes one of the duplicates but leaves the other - it's because the duplicate value of item "a" comes with a y value of 0 before the non zero value of 3. Is there a way around this without using groupbys and sorting etc?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your desired data set?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keep=False` to mark all duplicated cases as `True`:

```
df[~df.id.duplicated(keep=False) | (df.id.duplicated(keep=False) & (df.y.astype(int) > 0))]

#   id  y   z
#1  b   3   3
#2  c   5   6
#3  a   3   4
```

---

By default, `duplicated()` takes `first` as argument, and the first occurrence is not considered as duplicated, here are some further examples:

```
df.id.duplicated()

#0    False
#1    False
#2    False
#3     True
#4     True
#Name: id, dtype: bool

#df.id.duplicated(keep=False)            # all duplicated ids are marked as True
#0     True
#1     True
#2    False
#3     True
#4     True
#Name: id, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

The function **duplicated** have an option to return all duplicate value in the Series. More details here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html

You can simply slice the original DataFrame matching exactly your criteria.

```
# keep only what is not duplicated and equals to 0
df[~(df['id']duplicated(False) & (df['y']=='0'))]
```

I would recommend to 'fix' your dtype for the column 'y' as currently is a string from your example. Just make sure it's the correct dtype ('int' or 'string') to prevent any unwanted issues!